# Bootstrap 3 - Navbar active class

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

```
$("#houses a:contains('Houses')").parent().addClass('active');
```

```
<body id="houses">
  <li><a href="houses.php">Houses</a></li> 
</body>
```

When I click on the nav(houses), at the inspect element it adds the class active but it doesn't change the color of the nav. adds class but no effect.

I have been trying to follow a tutorial. It seems to work fine there, just not for me.

Comment: Post your codes, better make a fiddle - JSfiddle.net

Comment: Here it is sir http://jsfiddle.net/Vnsrm/

Comment: There is no click event. may be you have to explain bit more on what do you wanted.

Comment: my problem is it adds the active class to the li but it doesn't have the effect. the color is the same as the other li that do not have the active class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gotcha,

You are missing navbar theme class on `.navbar` div. Add class `.navbar-default` to `.navbar` and all done.

**Updated HTML**

```
<section class="navbar navbar-default">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="index.php">New Listings</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="homes.php">Houses</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="land.php">Land</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="mortgagecalc.php">Mortgage Calculator</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">   <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">For Pros<span class="caret"></span></a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
                            <li> <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Register for Caraga Homes</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li> <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Post a listing for free</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- drop down Menu -->
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </section>
```

And all done.  Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/shekhardesigner/r2qaZ/

Comment: I watched the video again. and there was no navbar-default but it worked for him flawlessly. Maybe it was a different version of bootstrap 3.0. tnx again.

Comment: Seems you saw video for Bootstrap 2.3.2

Comment: Theme classes are from Bootstrap 3.0

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        var url = window.location.href;
        $('.nav a[href="'+url+'"]').parent().addClass('active');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Good answers contain source code and a short explanation to help other viewers. Please consider adding a few lines of text explaining your solution and what makes it useful.